# Explanation for an organism that feeds off the life of others

Tags: biology, anatomy, supernatural

A character of legendary status has the ability to bleed the life out of the objects around him. He was born with the ability on a lesser scale, but now it’s progressed to the point where he is able to feed off a life simply by touch alone.

I’m having a hard time explaining how his body allows him to do it. Would it be possible that the process is similar to how a leech drains the blood from whatever it attaches to? Could there be an explanation, biological or supernatural, for how this happens?

Comment: What are you trying to ask, here? Do you want to know if there's any non-supernatural way of having this happen? (There really isn't) You want to know what such a supernatural effect would look like to biology?

Comment: I’d like to know a possible explaination for how this happens, The Nate

Comment: Magic - nothing scientific covers it.

Comment: You can't feed on "life".  "Life" is not a scientific power source.  Being alive is a condition, it is not a state of matter or energy that could possibly be consumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assume in this world there exists as part of its natural phenomena the so-called "vital force". This is a completely repudiated scientific concept devised when our understanding was less developed. A person with the ability to transfer the vital force from other living creatures would resemble your life-feeder.

There's no reason why, in this case, you couldn't postulate that vital force can drawn off from another organism almost like electricity. It might even be possible to develop a technology to transfer vital force in this world. Thus providing technological vampirism to extend the lives of the rich and powerful. Or even reanimate creatures constructed from human and animal parts like good old Victor Frankenstein.

This does mean biology in your fictional world will be more than somewhat different from that in ours. The vital force concept was a real idea. History and the March of Science has totally repudiated its validity, now it's just bad pseudoscience, but there's no reason it couldn't be used in a fictional world.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you investigate Chinese medicine and their concept of [qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi) (the Wikipedia article linked makes a good starting point). The movement of energy through the body is central to even their modern medical philosophy, and it underlies areas ranging from acupuncture to martial arts to [architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feng_shui). This concept has lead to a great number of literary characters in Chinese and adapted works who have the ability to leech the qi of other people.